# Heroku failed to find application app error

Tags: python, pandas, heroku, plotly-dash

Trying to deploy my dash plotly dashboard on Heroku but getting this error:

```
2020-02-12T20:06:28.207580+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn app:server`
2020-02-12T20:06:34.455328+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-02-12T20:07:03.644528+00:00 app[web.1]: WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:10)
2020-02-12T20:07:04.647635+00:00 app[web.1]: WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:11)
2020-02-12T20:07:15.625829+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/" host=kalinaxchallenge.herokuapp.com request_id=f2e2ef3e-c454-45fc-a5f0-f3e4fa1f59e1 fwd="197.221.254.77" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2020-02-12T20:07:22.939065+00:00 app[web.1]: Failed to find application: 'app'
2020-02-12T20:07:28.354927+00:00 app[web.1]: Failed to find application: 'app'
2020-02-12T20:07:29.073920+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2020-02-12T20:07:28.813680+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=kalinaxchallenge.herokuapp.com request_id=7c1977fe-5495-4327-990f-68a433ed2269 fwd="197.221.254.77" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=11173ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2020-02-12T20:07:29.059525+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 4
```

my procfile:

```
web: gunicorn app:server
```

and my requirements.txt

```
dash_core_components==1.5.1
dash==1.6.1
dash_html_components==1.0.2
pandas==0.25.2
plotly==4.2.1
gunicorn==19.0.0
numpy==1.17.4
```

and my app.py

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run_server(debug=True)
```

The app runs perfectly locally

Seems to be a weird error message, atleast to me because this is the structure of my project

```
Procfile
app.json
app.py
dataset1
dataset2
requirements.txt
```

I'm not sure why its failing to find the app application when its right there

NOTE: I don't have a folder named app and deleted app.json

Comment: If you upgrade `gunicorn` to 19.5.0 in your `requirements.txt` file, do you run into the same issue?

Comment: tried that and upgrading to 19.9.0 @sumshyftw

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by adding this line to my app.py

```
server = app.server
```